# show arrows in QStackedWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm making a `GUI` using `Qt-Designer` and `Pyqt5` in `python 3.6.3`.

The `GUI` has a `QStackedWidget` with 2 pages. Each page has a arrow above so the user can switch between them(as showen in `Qt-Designer` (see pciture below)).

The problem is, when I convert the `ui` to `py` using `pyuic5`and then run the `py` code the arrows to switch the pages of the `QStackedWidget` are disappeared.

How the arrows can be showen while running the `py` code?

code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(314, 216)
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(Dialog)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 211, 101))
        self.stackedWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.stackedWidget.setStyleSheet("selection-background-color: rgb(255, 255, 127);\n"
"background-color: rgb(154, 154, 154);\n"
"border-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"selection-color: rgb(85, 255, 0);")
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.stackedWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.stackedWidget.setLineWidth(1)
        self.stackedWidget.setMidLineWidth(2)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.page)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 40, 113, 25))
        self.lineEdit_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(113, 0))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 68, 19))
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(68, 0))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.page_2)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 40, 113, 25))
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(113, 0))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);\n"
"border-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 68, 19))
        self.label_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(68, 0))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "I/P1 ="))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "I/P2 ="))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

the right view of `QStackedWidget`

[image]

Comment: but I don't want to change the style to fusion. I want to keep it win. style

Comment: yea i mean WindowsVista-Style. and I have tried Fusion and the problem is the same.